# Match string using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following variable:

```
var test = category~[330526|330519]^Size{1}~[m]
```

How do I match just to get `category~[330526|330519]` using regex.

This value can also change so it could be `category~[3303226|333219]`

Comment: Is that value supposed to be a string?

Comment: Why not just `test.replace('^Size{1}~[m]','')`?

Comment: In the spirit of teaching a man to fish... Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html, you're probably looking for `\d` and `+`.

Comment: That ain't JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

Just try with:

```
test.split('^')[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var test = 'category~[330526|330519]^Size{1}~[m]';

var result = test.split('^').shift();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jHXXU/)

Answer (score 1):

You could;

```
 result = test.substr(0, test.indexOf("]") +1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
category~\[\d+\|\d+\]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `category` text can be anything. I'm not down voting, just noting.

Comment: Your welcome - feel free to accept it as the best answer if it is the one you are going with.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a Regex, this one doesn't care about what the category is `(.*~\[\d+\|\d+\])`. Here is a [Rubular to prove it](http://rubular.com/). But I have to say, the answer by @hsz is really the most insightful. The `split` is probably the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach...

```
var test = 'category~[330526|330519]^Size{1}~[m]';

var result = test.replace(/\^.+/,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

"category~[330526|330519]^Size{1}~[m]".replace(/(category~[\d+\|\d+]).*/,"$1"), you should get the string, or you can use match as well.